# How to remove min-width:80px; from the site?

Tags: css

I have a search area on [this](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/bankalhabib/) website. The search button has a min width of 80 px which is coming from bootstrap. How can I remove/override the width?

Comment: Create a selector for that element and override that style.

Comment: just use `.search_box_class_name { min-width: width_you_want!important; }`

Comment: you can remove `btn` class.

Comment: Please include all the relevant code required to reproduce the issue in the question itself. A link is not suitable, if it dies or the problem gets fixed this question will lose all value to users with similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add .btn class in your code and mark your width as important

```
.btn{
 width : <your value> px !important
}
```

Answer (score 24):

you can remove `btn` class

### OR

you can override using its id selector and setting min-width to unset

```
min-width: unset;
```

in your example

```
input#searchsubmit {
    min-width: unset;
}
```

Comment: I was about tho say the same thing @SublymeRick.

Answer (score 1):

Add `.btn` selector in your custom CSS to override bootstrap css.

```
.btn {width: [n]px} /*set your desired width*/
```

Or

Add a new selector and set the width for that.

That's it.

Comment: And what if the OP wants to keep that style, but only wants to change it for only that one element?

Comment: Then your very first comment comes to rescue. :)

Answer (score -1):

Add a custom class to the button with no min width.

If you only want to change this button and not the others.

Example:

```
no-min-width {
    min-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: no-min-width is missing the dot, in your example. This is also the wrong way to do it. See @shaymmakawana.me's answer.

Answer (score -1):

this will work 100%

```
input#searchsubmit {
    min-width: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Its already inheriting from bootstrap so you're just telling it to do the same thing its doing...